# Enable JQuery for only one JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing what's essentially a plugin for a website that already uses the $ symbol in it's own Javascript code. I want my plugin to use JQuery, but I can't change their code to add a jQuery.noConflict(), so after my plugin loads all of the code for the main site starts to crash.

Is there a way to enable JQuery for only one Javascript file? 
Or is there a version of .noConflict() that works across *all* Javascript files for a web page?

I'm starting to look at some pretty odd ball solutions (such as a wrapper JS function that adds JQuery, then runs the function you want, then removes JQuery), so I'd appreciate it if someone can point out something I've missed before I do something I'll regret.

Edit: The more I test the more it looks like there might be something else going on instead. noConflict() does seem to be working, as I am able to make sure my script is the first one to run afterwards.

Comment: you could just use the `jQuery` instead of `$`. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: You don't need to edit their code to use noConflict. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from using `jQuery` in place of `$`?

Can't you just change the order of your scripts and have `jQuery.noConflict()` called earlier?

Comment: in my opinion, that isn't your problem. Build your plugin, specify it needs jquery to be on the page, and that's it. Let the dev of said website include it and use no conflict. Including jquery directly in your plugin is more likely to cause problems than not assuming this is for more than one specific website.

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm I could use jQuery in my own code, but that doesn't prevent their code from still using $.

Comment: @Nol maybe I'm missing something, because even with JQuery and my code being the last two imports and having noConflict at the start of my code I'm still crashing an otherwise stable page.

Comment: @Dr.Cyanide Could you provide an example of what you are doing?  Perhaps edit your question to show your script tags and when you try to use `noConflict()`.   It sounds like something is out of order, but I can't tell what from just this.

Comment: @Nol more testing makes it look like it might be an issue with one of my functions. With the noConflict added I'm able to use the rest of the main website without issues, but running my own code causes the site to start to crash. Regardless, the initial question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look into the possibility of bundling modules and loading them dynamically. Tools like webpack, systemjs, gulp, and grunt could be helpful for your use case. Without those tools, I am not certain how else to achieve what you're looking to do.